# Infinite loop reading file into array

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, fstream

I have an infinite loop while trying to read a file. File is saved from user input, then it is to be read, finally, displayed using a separate function.

Here is my read function. The loop is not finding the eof(); from the file. I can't see what the issue is. No compiler errors.

```
void read(HouseholdItems items[AMOUNT], fstream& myFile, fstream& yourFile)
{
    myFile.open("insured.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);                                      // Open myFile
    yourFile.open("uninsured.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);                                  // Open yourFile
    for(int i = 0; i < AMOUNT; i++)
    {
        myFile.read(reinterpret_cast <char*>(&items[i]),sizeof(&items[i]));
        yourFile.read(reinterpret_cast <char*>(&items[i]),sizeof(&items[i]));
        for(i = 0; i < AMOUNT; i++)
        {
            while (myFile)
            {
                cout << "description: ";
                cout << items[i].description << endl;
                cout << "quantity: ";
                cout << items[i].quantity << endl;
                cout << "price: ";
                cout << items[i].price << endl;
                cout << "insured: ";
                cout << items[i].insured << endl;
            }
        }

    }

    myFile.close();
    yourFile.close();

}
```

Comment: Maybe the loop is not finding the EOF because it's not even looking for it

Comment: I tried using the eof(); Same problem, from what I have read, you don't have to use the eof(); it automatically looks for it. Is that not true?

Comment: 'sizeof(&items[i])' is most definitely wrong

Comment: Why you have a for the same variable ( i ) than the outside for?

Comment: @SamIam [technically he is checking `eof()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/), assuming MyFile is an ifstream

Comment: lcjury, the 'i' is to loop through the array element.

Comment: @dwcanillas I am using fstream for the files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following loop can never end : no modification is made to `myFile` inside its body :

```
        while (myFile)
        {
            cout << "description: ";
            cout << items[i].description << endl;
            cout << "quantity: ";
            cout << items[i].quantity << endl;
            cout << "price: ";
            cout << items[i].price << endl;
            cout << "insured: ";
            cout << items[i].insured << endl;
        }
```

You have to read the file inside the `while` loop for it to end.

Besides, you most likely have a variable name conflict: you have two `for` loops that use the same variable `i` ; which is presumably not what you want.

Comment: That solved the infinite loop. Thanks for the tip. Makes total sense.
Deleted one for loop.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is `while(myFile)`, since nothing about `myFile` changes in that loop.  It isn't clear what it is you mean for that loop to accomplish, so I can't say what to replace it with.  (It does seem problematic that you have nested `for` loops, but don't seem to have a table of data.)

Answer (score 1):

The answers by @ScottHunter and @Ekelog already answer the real problem. The following are peripheral problems.

These lines are not right:

```
myFile.read(reinterpret_cast <char*>(&items[i]),sizeof(&items[i]));
yourFile.read(reinterpret_cast <char*>(&items[i]),sizeof(&items[i]));
```

You need to use:

```
myFile.read(reinterpret_cast <char*>(&items[i]),sizeof(items[i]));
                                                    // ^^ Drop the &
yourFile.read(reinterpret_cast <char*>(&items[i]),sizeof(items[i]));
                                                    // ^^ Drop the &
```

Comment: As true as that is, it doesn't address the infinite loop.

Comment: @ScottHunter, agree. Feel free to take these lines and add them to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this in while

`while (!myFile.eof())
        {
            cout << "description: ";
            cout << items[i].description << endl;
            cout << "quantity: ";
            cout << items[i].quantity << endl;
            cout << "price: ";
            cout << items[i].price << endl;
            cout << "insured: ";
            cout << items[i].insured << endl;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

See inline comments:

```
void read(HouseholdItems items[AMOUNT], fstream& myFile, fstream& yourFile)
{
    // since you open and close those files here, you probably
    // want to declare them here instead as a function parameter
    myFile.open("insured.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);                                      // Open myFile
    yourFile.open("uninsured.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);                                  // Open yourFile
    // test in the loop
    for(int i = 0; i < AMOUNT && myFile && yourFile; i++)
    {
        // these two reads do not make sense, the second one
        // will overwrite the data just read by the first one...
        // maybe you meant that one of the file might be smaller?
        // or maybe to compare the results in some ways (in which
        // case you need two arrays)
        myFile.read(reinterpret_cast <char*>(&items[i]),sizeof(items[i]));
        yourFile.read(reinterpret_cast <char*>(&items[i]),sizeof(items[i]));

        // write current result
        cout << "description: ";
        cout << items[i].description << endl;
        cout << "quantity: ";
        cout << items[i].quantity << endl;
        cout << "price: ";
        cout << items[i].price << endl;
        cout << "insured: ";
        cout << items[i].insured << endl;
    }

    myFile.close();
    yourFile.close();    
}
```

As a side note:

- Your second `for()` loop reused the `i` variable which means it would not work at all as expected.
- As pointed out by others the `sizeof()` was wrong, you could also use `sizeof(items[0])` since all items are equal in size.
- As mentioned by SamIAm, the `while()` was blocking because the file was not being read so the EOF never actually reached in the file.
- As shown in the comments, the file objects should probably be defined in the function instead of outside and passed in as references.